# Task WebRequest silent fail in ContinueWith Method

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await, task, webrequest

I'm trying to have a console application:

1. Spin up concurrent tasks for a collection of items
2. Each task hits a REST service to retrieve current info for item (JSON)
3. Post the result of first call into another service to retrieve updated details
4. As each task completes, I want to insert data into DB.

I'm creating a list of tasks that use the ContinueWith() method.

```
foreach (var instance in waveInstances)
{
   getTasks.Add(firstService(instance, vendor).ContinueWith(t => secondService(t.Result), TaskContinuationOptions.AttachedToParent));
}
while (getTasks.Count > 0)
{
    var firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(getTasks);
    getTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);       
    var instance = await firstFinishedTask;

    WriteToDb(instance);
}
```

My problem comes in the secondService I call in the ContinueWith().  My code looks basically like:

```
private async Task<taskData> filterForVendor(string json)
{
   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
   request.Method = "POST";
   request.Accept = "application/json";
   request.ContentType = "application/json";

   using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
   {
      streamWriter.Write(json);
      streamWriter.Flush();
      streamWriter.Close();
   }
   ...Continue to GetResponseString
```

I'm using the exact same style, but only doing a GET in the firstService.  I even tried duplicating the method exactly as a test but it still just ends silently when trying to GetRequestStream(), why is this happening in the ContinueWith() part only?

Comment: Have you turned on first chance exceptions?

Comment: Please post your `Main(string[] args)` method. You should have a line of code where you explicitly block and wait for a Task to complete (something like `MyAsycCode().Wait()`)